# Чёрный экран в Kali Linux после установки

Tags: linux, virtualbox, установка, kali-linux

Загрузил Kali Linux и запустил в виртуальной машине VirtualBox. После всех настроек он кажется установился на виртуалке но есть только чёрный экран с мигающим   **_**   нижним подчёркиванием. никак нечего не получается туда писать, в том числе и пароль, но получается запустить терминал нажав Alt+Ctrl+F3(или F2), и заполнив туда логин и пароль.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Тип вм менеджера какой? Что ставили в качестве WM? Какие настройки графики? Что в sylog?  dmesg?

Comment: Виртуальная машина Virtual Machine, Kali не запускается чтобы какие-то настройки проводить. Я только его установил.

Comment: На втором снимке это рабочая машина, откуда это?

Comment: нажимая Alt+Ctrl+F3 открывается терминал где нужно авторизаваться. Это единственное что получается делать.

Comment: Так там и проверте, что у вас за ошии в логах - этот терминал таже самая ось только без графики. `grep -I "err\|war\|fatal\|prob" /var/log/syslog` окажите что выдаст

Comment: https://ibb.co/M2B5bRJ

Comment: @Hellseher это ссылка на скриншот

Comment: startx пробовали?

Comment: Всё заработало полсе startx. Огромное вам спасибо

Comment: Но всё приходится делать снова и снова каждый раз

Comment: такое бывает, вот ссылка на форум где была подобная проблема и как ее решили, надеюсь это окажется для вас полезной информацией, желаю удачи) https://codeby.net/threads/problema-s-chernym-ehkranom-v-kali.60359/

Comment: Ну потому что у вас сломана автоматическая система входа в графический интерфейс. В зависимости от системы инициализации (systemd, system init V, ...) это настраивается соответствующим образом.

Comment: Скорее всего в Биосе надо включить виртуализацию

Comment: Скорее всего, при установке Вы пропустили этап с выбором места установки GRUB.